# API Data Return to HTML

Tags: php, json, api, response

I have added new data to my API. I want to return it as plain text

This is the API response PHP returns.

```
 {
    "apiVersion":"1.0", 
    "data":{ 
            "location":"London",:
            { 
             "pressure":"1021",
              "temperature":"23", 
              "skytext":"Sky is Clear",
              "humidity":"40", 
              "wind":"18.36 km/h", 
              "date":"07-10-2015", 
              "day":"Friday" 
             }
      }
```

I want to return the pressure value on my html page so my users can see the reading. I am having issues displaying it.

This is my PHP api.php

```
require_once('./includes/config.php');
require_once('./includes/functions.php');
error_reporting(0);
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;');

$city = $_GET['city'];

if(isset($city)) {

    $weather = new Weather($conf['apikey'], $_GET['f']);
    $weather_current = $weather->get($city, 0, 0, null, null);

    $now = $weather->data(0, $weather_current);

    if($now['location'] !== NULL) {
        echo '{"apiVersion":"1.0", "data":{ "location":"'.$now['location'].'", "temperature":"'.$now['temperature'].'", "pressure":"'.$now['pressure'].'", "skytext":"'.$now['description'].'", "humidity":"'.$now['humidity'].'", "wind":"'.$now['windspeed'].'", "date":"'.$now['date'].'", "day":"'.$now['day'].'" } }';
    } else {
        echo '{"apiVersion":"1.0", "data":{ "error":"The \'city\' requested is not available, make sure it\'s a valid city." } }';
    }
} else {
    echo '{"apiVersion":"1.0", "data":{ "error":"You need to specify the city parameter" } }';
}
```

Comment: `{"apiVersion":"1.0", "data":{ "location":"London":{ 
"pressure":"1021", "temperature":"23", "skytext":"Sky is Clear",
 "humidity":"40", "wind":"18.36 km/h", "date":"07-10-2015", 
"day":"Friday" } }`

Comment: how do i show the json result im still trying to debug this just need a little help fixing the issue

Comment: If you can provide more context it would be much easier to help you. As of now we have very little to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into? What you're showing is JSON (non-valid at this point), not an API.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch data from a JSON source you should parse the data with the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method. You can then use the second parameter to parse it into an array. If you omit the second parameter you would get an array of objects.

**Important:** It seems your JSON has a syntax error too. I have added a `weather` key before the weather information.

```
$data = '{
    "apiVersion":"1.0",
    "data":{
        "location":"London",
        "weather":{              // Notice the new key!
            "pressure":"1021",
            "temperature":"23",
            "skytext":"Sky is Clear",
            "humidity":"40",
            "wind":"18.36 km/h",
            "date":"07-10-2015",
            "day":"Friday"
        }
    }
}';

$json = json_decode($data, true);
```

You should then be able to fetch the pressure as an associative array.

```
$pressure = $json['data']['weather']['pressure']; // Equals: 1021
```

Hope this can help you, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to validate your JSON. It is missing some key things that will keep you from being able to parse it. Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to verify your JSON.

After modification the JSON to make it valid I did the following:

```
$json = '{"apiVersion":"1.0", "data":{ "location":"London", "data":{ "pressure":"1021", "temperature":"23", "skytext":"Sky is Clear", "humidity":"40", "wind":"18.36 km/h", "date":"07-10-2015", "day":"Friday" }}}';

$obj_style = json_decode($json);
$array_style = json_decode($json, true);

echo $obj_style->data->data->pressure;
echo $array_style['data']['data']['pressure'];
```

Using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) I was able to setup a way to parse the JSON two ways, once as an object and once as an array (adding the `true` flag returns the results as an array).

From there all you have to do is drill town to the bits of information that you want to display.